# Everything is gone, but the hearts remain

Tags: wordplay

I have a story to tell. Don't be surprised if the story sounds incomplete; actually I omitted a part of it: or rather, the heart of the story..

> There was some cash, but not mine. Some stupid persons had to be removed from the networks. The boss of the metalworkers didn't get a wash. A mixture of sulfur and urea was brought, but Sulea didn't come. This unexpected event didn't happen at the MIT. He raises no chickens. He has the appearance of a skeleton; he's no boss, though. He is indefensible, but not incompetent.

**What does this story mean? What could the omitted part be?**

Comment: Is this a series of Cryptic Clues?

Comment: @Chris Not quite... ;)

Comment: The accepted answer does not cover the omitted part :)

Comment: @ManojKumar It does, see towards the end of that answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get started...

There was some cash, but not mine.

> Money (cash) - my (mine) = **one**

Some stupid persons had to be removed from the networks.

> Networks - nerks (stupid people, just learned this British slang) = **two**

The boss of the metalworkers didn't get a wash.

> Lathreeve (head officer of a lathe) - lave (wash) = **three**

A mixture of sulfur and urea was brought, but Sulea didn't come.

> Sulfur and urea make [Sulfourea](http://www.chemindustry.com/chemicals/013568180.html), take away Sulea = **four**

This unexpected event didn't happen at the MIT.  (Thanks, @Wu33o!)

> Misevent - MIT = **seven**

He raises no chickens.

> heightens (raises) - hens (chickens) = **eight**

He has the appearance of a skeleton; he's no boss, though.

> boniness - boss = **nine**

He is indefensible, but not incompetent.

> untenable (indefensible) - unable (incompetent) = **ten**

So we're missing the "heart" of the matter.  The omitted part could be:

> After dropping a couple twenties on it, he listened to an old record.  = **five**  (fortyfive - forty)
>
>  He stayed away from the City of Angels when he got his vision surgically corrected. = **six**  (lasix - la)

Comment: Nice start! For the fourth line, you may use [this](http://www.chemindustry.com/chemicals/013568180.html) :-)

Comment: Is it okay if I add the solution for the MIT event?

Comment: The last one (ten) is not correct. The subtractions are not simply anagrams; they have a definite pattern (as you have probably already noticed).

Comment: @Ankoganit Got it.  Will try again. (Penitent seemed like a stretch.)

Comment: Better now. BTW, the only remaining one is a rather uncommon word.:-)

Comment: Smith-immerse=Three?

Comment: @Techidiot Smith might be right, but need a boss starting with "ree".

Comment: The Smiths is also a band. May be its lead. Not sure if I am speaking trivial.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't really expect the solver to make new puzzles for the missing numbers! You might want to include the explanations too for stupids like me (it feels uneasy when you can't solve puzzles resembling you own :D). BTW, the missing one is really uncommon (it's not even in SOWPODS, but is in OneLook), so here's a hint: it's 9-lettered.

Comment: Dan, you are a God hahaha nice one